# Compare time-varying series

Tags: time-series

[image: time varying series]

I want to compare how the position angle during reach 2 (green) and 3 (blue) varies from the control reach 1 (red). It is mainly the middle section of the reach that I am concerned with, at the point of maximum velocity.

I would say that I would like to use statistics to say that 2 and 3 (green and blue) differ from the control (red). (Accept the hypothesis?) I'm am unsure of which hypothesis test to use.

Comment: The approach will depend on how you measure the difference between the cases. Would you integrate the absolute or squared difference (w.r.t. the vertical axis) between the series across the horizontal axis? Which characteristic of the series is of interest? Do you want to test whether their means differ? variances differ? Yet something else? You would estimate the parameter of interest and see, in light of estimation precision (confidence interval, standard error, etc.) how different the different cases (red, green, blue) are.